# Class not found/loaded in silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Hello I have this service in my config/config.php

```
$app['JsonFetcher'] = $app->share(function($app) {
    return new app\custom\JsonFetcher($app);
});
```

The JsonFetcher is in app/custom/JsonFetcher.php

and in my composer.json I have

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "custom": "app"
        }
    }
```

Somehow I still get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'app\custom\JsonFetcher' not found in /Users/username/Sites/site-demo/config/config.php on line 15

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your class namespaced correctly? (custom\JsonFetcher)

Comment: Have you registered your namespace by calling $loader->add('name', 'path')?

Comment: @WojciechJasiński that's not neccessary when using composer.